# delete array[x] deleting value but not the whole element

Tags: javascript

I have an object which has duplicate values so i used delete new_object[1] to delete the value but when I see this in console its showing undefined in object 0800

```
["293", undefined, "298", "297"]
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information to to properly answer this question.

Comment: Use `splice`. Not delete

Comment: what info you need @CliffRibaudo ? the code or the full object or something else ?

Comment: show your code illustrating what you were doing to remove the duplicate values.

Comment: [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) if for plain **objects**, not arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
arr.splice(index, 1);
```

`delete` only removes the element, but keeps the indexes. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript) is similar in nature and provides more information.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use *[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)*

```
a = ["1","2","3"];
a.splice(1,0)
console.log(a) //["1","3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

var test = [1,2,3,4];

delete test[1];

now if you print the test variable, you will get

## => [ 1, , 3, 4 ]

that is why you have got undefined

like everyone here is answering, you should use splice

test.splice(1,1);

and now print the test variable will give you

## =>  [ 1, 3, 4, 5 ]

Answer (score 1):

you need to use **splice()** in order to remove the value from the array. What you are doing is simply setting it to undefined.

```
var myArray = ['295', '296', '297', '298'];

// removes 1 element from index 2
var removed = myArray.splice(2, 1);
// myArray is ['295', '296', '298'];
// removed is ['297']
```

**Reference** from [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> The splice() method changes the content of an array by removing
>   existing elements and/or adding new elements.